# Apple Mach-O Linker Error in React-RCCText-framework

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm new to xCode, I've my app working on android (using windows) then I have to make a build for ios, after some troubleshooting I'm stuck in this problem, I've this error under 'React-RCCText-framework':

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_YGNodeIsDirty", referenced from:

-[RCTBaseTextInputShadowView uiManagerWillPerformMounting] in RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.o

-[RCTTextShadowView uiManagerWillPerformMounting] in RCTTextShadowView.o

"_YGNodeMarkDirty", referenced from:

-[RCTBaseTextInputShadowView dirtyLayout] in RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.o

-[RCTTextShadowView dirtyLayout] in RCTTextShadowView.o

"_YGNodeSetDirtiedFunc", referenced from:

-[RCTBaseTextShadowView insertReactSubview:atIndex:] in RCTBaseTextShadowView.o

-[RCTBaseTextShadowView removeReactSubview:] in RCTBaseTextShadowView.o

"_YGNodeGetContext", referenced from:

_RCTBaseTextInputShadowViewMeasure in RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.o

_RCTTextInputShadowViewBaseline in RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.o

_RCTInlineViewYogaNodeDirtied in RCTBaseTextShadowView.o

_RCTTextShadowViewMeasure in RCTTextShadowView.o

_RCTTextShadowViewBaseline in RCTTextShadowView.o

"_YGNodeSetMeasureFunc", referenced from:

-[RCTBaseTextInputShadowView initWithBridge:] in RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.o

-[RCTTextShadowView initWithBridge:] in RCTTextShadowView.o

"_YGNodeSetBaselineFunc", referenced from:

-[RCTBaseTextInputShadowView initWithBridge:] in RCTBaseTextInputShadowView.o

-[RCTTextShadowView initWithBridge:] in RCTTextShadowView.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is my Pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.3'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end




post_install do |installer|
add_flipper_pods!
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if ['RNFBApp'].include?(target.name)
      target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'GoogleUtilities'})
target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'FirebaseAuth'})
      target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'FirebaseAnalytics'})
    elsif target.name.eql?('RNFBAnalytics')
      target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'FirebaseAnalytics'})
      target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'GoogleAppMeasurement'})
      target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'nanopb'})
 target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'FirebaseAuth'})
      target.add_system_framework(installer.pods_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'GoogleUtilities'})
    end
  end
end


pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end


  end
end
pre_install do |installer|
Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end
target 'GENUSAPP' do
  # Pods for 


#pod 'react-native-flipper', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-flipper', :configuration => 'Debug'
#use_native_modulconfig.js

 use_frameworks!
  pod 'ViroReact', :path => '../node_modules/react-viro/ios/'
  pod 'ViroKit', :path => '../node_modules/react-viro/ios/dist/ViroRenderer/'
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

pod 'GoogleUtilities'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
#pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'


  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'


  target 'GENUSAPPTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few 
 #add_flipper_pods!
 # post_install do |installer|
 #   flipper_post_install(installer)
 # end
end
```